# Stuck in black screen closing steam

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, steam

I have purchased a brand new dell XPS 15 9560

```
Specs:

- Windows 10
- Intel i7 7th generation (Kaby Lake)
- 16GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
- 512 GB SSD
```

Everything works fine, except for steam: I downloaded Portal 2. But when I try to close the game. I am stuck with a black screen (no mouse cursor or so), A hard reboot is all I can do at the moment to get it working again.

The OS was pre-installed with all the necessary drivers, so I did not have to install some custom drivers myself.

Things I tried:

- Open the NVIDIA controle panel and switched the global graphics processor from the 'integrated Intel Graphics processor' to the ´High-end NVIDIA processor' (So the GTX 1050). But this didn't fix the problem.

Are some of you familiar with this problem? Do you have any advise on how to solve the problem?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Does this issue occur with other games or applications?

Comment: I dont have any trouble with other applications. For other games, dont know this is the only game I have installed at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was lucky that I ran into this post:

https://steamcommunity.com/app/207350/discussions/0/828925849481059703/

Changing the display adapter (Intel Integrated Graphics card) refresh rate (59hz to 60hz) did the trick for me, The reason why this works is not clear to me though.

Maybe it has something to do with when you close a steam game, windows tries to switches back from the NVIDIA card to the Intel card (I configured steam in the NVIDIA control panel it prefers to run steam with the NVIDIA GPU), and probably the NVIDIA card is running at 60 Hz (cannot verify this) while the Intel card is configured (by default) at 59 hz and so you run into trouble.